# An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8181/webmethod

Tags: wcf

I have a web service where I am returning a response named ProjectGroupGetInfo. While I compiling I am not getting any errors but when I invoke that method I see an error **An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8181/GAFPManagement. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.**
Following is my code for the response

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Enums;
using DELL.AFP.Management.ProjectGroup;
using Dell.AFP.BizManager;
using Dell.AFP.Entity;
using System.Data;


namespace AFPManagementServiceLibrary.ProjectGroup.Model
{
     [DataContract] 
    public class ProjectGroupInfoResponse
    {
       public ProjectGroupInfoResponse(Dell.AFP.Entity.ProjectGroup ProjectGroup)
       {
           if (ProjectGroup != null)
           {
               CreatedDate = ProjectGroup.CreatedDateTime;
               HigestProjectState = (AFPStateEnum)Convert.ToInt32(ProjectGroup.AFPState);
               CustomerGroup = (CustomerGroupEnum)ProjectGroup.CustomerGroupId;
               ProjectGroupName = ProjectGroup.Title;
               ProjectGroupOwner = ProjectGroup.CreatedByUser;
               IsRestricted = ProjectGroup.IsPublic;

           }
       }
       [DataMember]
       public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public AFPStateEnum HigestProjectState { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public CustomerGroupEnum CustomerGroup { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public string ProjectGroupName { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public string ProjectGroupOwner { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public bool IsRestricted { get; set; }

    }
}
```

my config file is:

```
        <!--Local GAFP Management Service Params-->
        <binding name="basicHttp1" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferSize="999999999"
          maxBufferPoolSize="999999999" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999"
          messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="999999999" maxStringContentLength="999999999"
            maxArrayLength="999999999" maxBytesPerRead="999999999" maxNameTableCharCount="999999999" />
        </binding>

        <!--Massive Service Params-->
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMassiveService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

        <!--AFP Archive Notification-->
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAFPArchiveNotification" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                   openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                   allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                   maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                   messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                   useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>

      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>

        <!--Server Path File Info Params-->
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServerPathFileInfo" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" algorithmSuite="Basic128" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

      <!-- Massive Service Client End Point-->
      <endpoint address="http://ausdwmssapp01.aus.amer.dell.com:9000/MassiveService/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMassiveService" contract="IMassiveService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMassiveService"/>

      <!-- File Info Service Client End Point-->
      <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServerPathFileInfo" contract="ServiceReference.IServerPathFileInfo" name="WSHttpBinding_IServerPathFileInfo"/>

      <!--AFP Archive Notification End Point-->
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAFPArchiveNotification" contract="IAFPArchiveNotification" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAFPArchiveNotification" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="AFPDBConnString" connectionString="Data Source=hydcdsitdb ;Initial Catalog=AFPSIT;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="GlobalAfp4Log" connectionString="data source= hydcdsitdb;initial catalog=AFPSITLOG;integrated security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="AgileDBConnString" connectionString="6923977bd9a34ce291c775ca531efe7f64c2cf1422100eb1408676deb90a878c9de0fe037305b00724e522e7387851f197446de48beb12ec6848189ce7f28ee8b4648559d951b888e7f0a4fe4595b47462bb0d420cf1e893f18b6b5e4e14c35c75d8f09481f6761d648ce08d8b1fd51ba7c749bb8e5d4a4dd4cde96841e94f3a3c735fe2a641ce655b875c1fb1d1043f3d848ffe197cd73ab6b4e268ce9df815f395d1f2cadef247698d770c20102aeb" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- <add key="ErrorCodesXml" value="ErrorCodesXml"/>-->
    <add key="ErrorCodesXml" value="C:\GAFP_4.1\source\Global AFP\AFPWeb\ErrorCodes.xml"/>
    <add key="ArchiveProcessPrefixFolder" value="GAFP"/>
    <add key="MassiveServiceURL" value="http://ausmvsitapp01.aus.amer.dell.com:9000/MassiveService/"/>
    <add key="AFPWcfServiceURL" value="http://KULUWAFP2APP01.kul.apac.dell.com:8900/AfpWcfService/"/>
    <add key="ServerPathFileInfoServiceBinding" value="WSHttpBinding_IServerPathFileInfo"/>
    <add key="MassiveWebServiceBinding" value="BasicHttpBinding_IMassiveService"/>
    <add key="MassiveCustomerGroup" value="BTOA"/>
    <add key="MassiveAccount" value="americas\ServiceMassiveDev"/>
    <add key="ProjectArchive_PackageMonitorTimeoutInMinutes" value="60"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: add exact error and your configuration file

Comment: the other methods are working fine but this method is not working.

Comment: It's difficult to help you just looking at your contract class, could you post your service class?
Is ProjectGroup class marked as DataContract?

Comment: You do know that a constructor in a class marked as a `[DataContrac]` will not get called unless the using application has a reference to the assembly that holds the data contract?  In other words, if the client is building the proxy via the WSDL, there will be no explicit constructor that runs your logic.